# Datatable horizontal scrollbar not visible

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a datatable with 20 columns when I set `[scrollable]="true"` the table does not show horizontal scroller?

How to achieve this?

Here is a plnkr of the problem
[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bbMoudhxbxCZNJxUFUs9?p=preview)

Comment: Share your code what you are tried in this ?

Comment: @Chandru I have edited the question and added a plnkr which shows the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="data" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200px" scrollWidth="600px" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="30">
            <p-column field="Col1" header="Column 1" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" [style]="{'width':'250px'}" [filterMatchMode]="'contains'"></p-column>
            <p-column field="Col2" header="Column 2" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" [style]="{'width':'250px'}" [filterMatchMode]="'contains'"></p-column>
            <p-column field="Col3" header="Column 3" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" [style]="{'width':'250px'}" [filterMatchMode]="'contains'"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: I don't want to set the size of the columns. Based on the text length it adjust it by itselft. That is how other data grids work